# Camel create file with specific name

Tags: java, apache-camel

```
@Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(from_location)
            .bean(transformer, "transformerMethod")
            .to(to_location);
  }
```

I have following code that is getting file from from location and process it in transformerMethod . My problem now is that need to create new file in bean ,  generate name ( inside of the bean ) and then i need to send it to the to location.

Problem is that i need to create it with specific name , and to do that from the bean ( processor ) and I could find documentation how to do that.

Could someone point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

Set a filename header (e.g. FOO) in the bean, then reference it in the URI of 'to_location' using the "filename" attribute: "file:to_location?filename=${header.FOO}"

More info can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/file2.html